# How to grab specific bits from a 256 bit message?

Tags: c++, c, winsock

I'm using winsock to receive udp messages 256 bits long. I use 8 32-bit integers to hold the data.

```
int32_t dataReceived[8];   

recvfrom(client, (char *)&dataReceived, 8 * sizeof(int), 0, &fromAddr, &fromLen);
```

I need to grab specific bits like, bit #100, #225, #55, etc. So some bits will be in dataReceived[3], some in dataReceived[4], etc.

I was thinking I need to bitshift each array, but things got complicated. Am I approaching this all wrong?

Comment: Please show the actual code that attempts to do the thing that you have described. We can't comment on whether it's good, bad or ugly if we can't see it. Please also review this to see what info is expected: [mcve]

Comment: C or C++, which language do you use?

Comment: `sizeof(int32_t)`!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you using `int32_t` type for buffer elements and not `uint32_t`?

I usually use something like this:

```
int bit_needed = 100;
uint32_t the_bit = dataReceived[bit_needed>>5] & (1U << (bit_needed & 0x1F));
```

Or you can use this one (but it won't work for sign in signed integers):

```
int bit_needed = 100;
uint32_t the_bit = (dataReceived[bit_needed>>5] >> (bit_needed & 0x1F)) & 1U;
```

In other answers you can access only lowes 8bits in each int32_t.

Answer (score 0):

When you count bits and bytes from 0:

```
int bit_needed = 100;
```

So:

```
int byte = int(bit_needed / 8);
int bit = bit_needed % 8;
int the_bit = dataReceived[byte] & (1 << bit);
```

If the recuired bit contains 0, then the_bit will be zero. If it's 1, then the_bit will hold 2 to the power of that bit ordinal place within the byte.

Comment: The array has `int32_t` elements, not `int8_t`. With `bit_needed = 100` you have index 12 in array

Answer (score 0):

You can make a small function to do the job.

```
uint8_t checkbit(uint32_t *dataReceived, int bitToCheck)
{
  byte = bitToCheck/32;
  bit = bitToCheck - byte*32;
  if( dataReceived[byte] & (1U<< bit))
    return 1;
  else 
    return 0;
}
```

Note that you should use `uint32_t` rather than `int32_t`, if you are using bit shifting. Signed integer bit shifts lead to unwanted results, especially if the MSbit is `1`.

Comment: Same issue as Israels answer. Array element type is `int32_t` not `int8_t`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a macro in C or C++ to check for specific bit:

```
#define bit_is_set(var,bit)     ((var) & (1 << (bit)))
```

and then a simple if:

```
if(bit_is_set(message,29)){
//bit is set
}
```